# Could not set WebLogic node manager log level to DEBUG

Tags: weblogic

The exception dumped on STDOUT is:

```
Jul 6, 2011 12:17:00 PM weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer main
SEVERE: Fatal error in node manager server
weblogic.nodemanager.common.ConfigException: Invalid log level value 'DEBUG' for property 'LogLevel"
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServerConfig.getLevelProperty(NMServerConfig.java:218)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServerConfig.<init>(NMServerConfig.java:159)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.init(NMServer.java:176)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.<init>(NMServer.java:141)
        at weblogic.nodemanager.server.NMServer.main(NMServer.java:337)
        at weblogic.NodeManager.main(NodeManager.java:31)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node manager is using log levels from `java.util.logging.Level`, and it is not using those used by WebLogic Server as it is documented by Oracle (`com.bea.logging.LogLevel`). The `LogLevel` property from `nodemanager.properties` can be set to: `SEVERE`, `WARNING`, `INFO` (default for WL Node Manger), `CONFIG`, `FINE`, `FINER`, `FINEST`, `ALL` and `OFF`.

`LogLevel` can be set also in the NodeManager startup script `WL_SERVER/server/bin/startNodeManager.sh`:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -DLogLevel=ALL"
```

See:

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/nodemgr/java_nodemgr.html#wp1070273
- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/apirefs.1111/e13941/com/bea/logging/LogLevel.html
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html

Comment: I have to test OFF and ALL to see if they are accepted by node manger.

Comment: They are both accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not the only one who has found this.

Even though the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13740/java_nodemgr.htm#BABIGGIE) says

> Node Manager uses the same logging levels as WebLogic Server.

There are several [forum](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1096575) [posts](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=767200) out there that report the same problem.

Comment: I've open service request at Oracle and they have confirmed that it is a documentation bug.